# How do you implement an interface in IronPython?

Tags: .net, interface, ironpython

The [FAQ that comes with IronPython 2.0.1](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&version=30) says the following:

> You can define interfaces in C#, build
>   those into a DLL, and then implement
>   those interfaces in Python code as
>   well as pass the python objects that
>   implement the interfaces to C# code.

I have googled and googled and googled, but haven't found how to do this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it with the regular inheritance syntax of Python:

```
class SomeClass (ISomeInterface):
    def SomeMethod(self, parameter):
        pass
```

Just "inherit" the interface, implement its methods as you would any other class method, and enjoy!

Comment: To implement properties in an interface, you would use `def get_SomeProperty(self):` and `def set_SomeProperty(self):`